# Javascript execution order incorrect

Tags: javascript, html

I've an issue where the JavaScript is executing before the rendering of the html.

I'm working through a code example from the book *Beginning JavaScript*.

Here's the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html langu="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Chapter 1, Example 2</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
        <p>Paragraph 1</p>
        <script>
            // script block 1
            alert("First Script Block");
        </script>
        <p>Paragraph 2</p>
        <script>
            // script block 2
            document.bgColor = "red";
            alert("Second Script Block");
        </script>
        <p>Paragraph 3</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I load the page:

1. The page is blank/white.
2. The first alert pops up.
3. I click OK.
4. The first paragraph displays.
5. Then the second alert pops up.
6. I click OK
7. The page changes from white to red.
8. Then the second and third paragraphs display.

I was expecting everything to display in the order I have it written, which is the behavior described in the book.

I've tried it in Chrome and Firefox with the same results. Also, I downloaded the example code, and it works exactly the same as I've written it.

Are my expectations incorrect, that the page should render in order?

Comment: rendering in a browser is not as predictable as you wish - having said that, the second paragraph appears and background does turn red before the second alert when I run your code (in firefox) - so, only Chrome displays in the so called "wrong order" - I wouldn't worry about it too much, real web designers never use alert/prompt etc anyway

Comment: In my case the background turns red **after** the second alert. So, as you see, it depends on the user agent.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - so, you're seeing the same order as in the question? You must be using "not firefox"

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, I'm using Chrome. Just tested on Firefox and it is doing the order you described. Safari is doing the Chrome order. I would also test on IE if IE were a browser...

Comment: behaviour in firefox is in this order: 1, 4, 2, 3, 8 (2nd only), 7, 5, 6, 8 (3rd para)

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - yes, if only it were :p - though, to be fair, IE and Edge both display the page in what I would say is the expected order (1, 4, 2, 3, 8a, 7, 5, 6, 8b) - Chrome is the "outlier" :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Chrome and Safari as well! Not to mention Opera... so, as you can see, it is a mess.

Comment: Well, Chrome/Safari/Opera are pretty much based on same codebase (webkit ancestry at least) - so, not really surprising)

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado - Hmm...I tried this in IE 11, and you're correct, it does display in the "correct" order. If it helps, I'm using FF 59.0.1 and Chrome 65.0.3325. And I'm on a PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code executes in the order you wrote it.

No, you should not expect rendering to happen at any specific point. You just change the document, the browser will then render it when it sees fit. This is a performance optimisation, if you would change the background color multiple times you wouldn't see it flickering but rather only the last value applied. Or if you changed multiple CSS properties, you would see all of them applied at the same time not one after the other.

Chrome is just waiting for your script execution to finish before rendering the updates. Blocking execution with a synchronous `alert` of course messes with that.